# React-Native pass title from Navigator to NavigatorIOS

Tags: javascript, title, react-native, navigator

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for quite some time now and cannot find anything that fixes it.

Here's the thing I'd like to accomplish.
I'm creating an app with a login screen. The login screen cannot have a navigation bar but has to navigate after the login to a component with a navigation bar with a custom title passed from the login component (the user name).

When the app loads, the App component will be loaded with the standard react Navigator component, which in turn renders the Login component. When the Login component renders, it will check for previous sessions and will render the main application (the Wrapper component) with the NavigatorIOS component which in turn renders another component (the List component, not shown in the code below).

Is it even possible? If so, how :)

I have the following code:

```
// The first main component,
// this will be loaded from the AppRegistry
var App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{
                    component: Login
                }}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                    return React.createElement(route.component, { navigator });         
                }} />
        )
    }
});

// The login component that
// renders and handles all login processes.
var Login = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        // ... login logic ...
        this.props.navigator.replace({
            component: Wrapper,
            // I want to pass a title here
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>Login page</Text>
        )
    }
});

// When logged in, the NavigatorIOS component will be
// shown, here is where I want to title previously passed
// from the login component.
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                initialRoute={{
                    component: List
                    title: // I want to fetch the title here
                }} />
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Login = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        // ... login logic ...
        this.props.navigator.replace({
            component: Wrapper,
            componentConfig : {
                title : "My New Title"
            }
            // I want to pass a title here
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>Login page</Text>
        )
    }
});

// When logged in, the NavigatorIOS component will be
// shown, here is where I want to title previously passed
// from the login component.
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                initialRoute={{
                    component: List
                    title: this.props.title
                }} />
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but `this.props.title` returns `undefined`. Is it componentConfig that handles this problem? Because I've searched google and the react-native github repo and I can't find anything about the existence of componentConfig.